# Does wave function of an electron itself move?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

As far as I know quantum mechanics, electrons in an atom in vacuum move accordingly a wave function (a complex scalar field), but the wave function itself does not move (except that the atom may transitionally move as a whole).

But if we could cause an electron revolve in vacuum around a charged sphere of macroscopic size, then the position of the electron could be measured almost exactly; and as follows from this the wave function itself moves (if it didn't move then the electron would be not localizable).

I wonder, why is it different for atoms and for the above described macroscopic case: In one case the wave function is strictly constant, and in the other one it isn't. What is the exact difference?

Comment: Electrons do not move according to a wavefunction. Quantum objects don't "move" in the classical sense at all. The assumptions going into this question are simply false, and it is unclear what you're actually trying to ask.

Comment: @ACuriousMind With all due respect, I think you are being a little harsh.  The OP has some serious misconceptions, but one reading of his question is "where am I going wrong."  One might argue that the question is not a good fit for S.E., but that's a different issue.

Comment: An experiment that tries to measure the position of an electron "almost exactly" is called a particle accelerator. Once you turn the energy on beyond approx. 1MeV, what you get is not more precise measurements, but ever more particles that are being created.

Comment: Homework: lookup the time-independent and time-dependent Schödinger equations and how their solutions are related to each other. Summarize your findings in a few paragraphs and be prepared to report to the class next week.

Comment: The (quantum) wave function is not an observable.

Comment: In the "oil drop" interpretation of quantum mechanics electrons do move according to a wave function: the bounce vertically in the wavefunction which is an actual medium, which also moves

Comment: @ACuriousMind "Electrons do not move according to a wavefunction". When saying that electrons move according to a wave function, I mean that electrons are observed in different positions at different times (according to a wave function). I call this "electrons move". Probably my usage of the word "move" disagrees with mainstream physics terminology, but it certainly makes sense.

Comment: @brucesmitherson: The "oil drop interpretation" doesn't do much good except to muddy the picture of what elementary particles are: they are measured quantities of a quantum field. The relevant physical object is the field and "the particles" are merely numbers on an experiment's printout that describe how the field has changed. The only mystery, to me, is why generations of physicists and layman have not been able to "grok" that a particle is no more "real" than the center of mass coordinates of earth are.